# Logical operator binding of AND and OR in Python

Tags: python, logical-operators

Yesterday while constructing a conditional statement I ran into what seems to me to be a strange precedence rule. The statement I had was

```
if not condition_1 or not condition_2 and not condition_3:
```

I found that

```
if True or True and False:
    # Evaluates to true and enters conditional
```

In my mind (and from previous experience in other languages) the `and` condition should have precedence as the statement is evaluated - so the statement should be equivalent to

```
if (True or True) and (False):
```

But in actual fact it is

```
if (True) or (True and False):
```

Which seems odd to me?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: [`or` has a lower precedence than `and`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From python wiki :

> The expression [**x and y**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#and) first evaluates x; if x is false, its **value** is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting **value** is returned.
>
> The expression **x or y** first evaluates x; if x is true, its **value** is returned; otherwise, y is evaluated and the resulting **value** is returned.

So in your case

```
if True or True and False:
```

Since interpreter encounters `True` before `or` it doesn't continue to `and` expression and evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 0):

As you said `and` has a higher preference, so your expression with parenthesis will be exactly what you said:

```
if (True) or (True and False)
```

Since `True or (anything)` will be `True` regardless anything here, the result will be `True`. Even if anything would be evaluated, which is not in a shortcut evaluation.